# Azure CloudTable.ExecuteBatch(TableBatchOperation) throws a storageexception. How can I find which operation(s) caused the exception?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I have this code for deleting some items:

```
    private static void DeleteBatch(IList<TableEntity> toDelete)
    {
        if(toDelete == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("toDelete");
        if(toDelete.Count == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("There is no elements in toDelete.");
        if(toDelete.GroupBy(e => e.PartitionKey).Count() > 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("The entities to delete must have the same PartitionKey.");

        Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, toDelete.Count, 100),
                         range =>
                         {
                             TableBatchOperation batchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();
                             for (Int32 i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
                                 batchOperation.Delete(toDelete[i]);
                             _table.ExecuteBatch(batchOperation);
                         });
    }
```

The table entities are passed with a * ETag.

Sometimes this will throw a `StorageException: The specified resource does not exist.` I presume this is a 404 HttpStatusCode. In this case I don't care whether it does not exist, so I want to ignore this exception for the operations that caused them. How can I ignore 404 for invididual TableOperations in the batch, or at least retry the batch operation for TableOperations that did not throw this exception (how do I know which operations failed). It feels very ineffective to do each operation individually just to be able to find which caused 404.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a batch operation, I don't think it's possible to ignore errors. There's one thing you could do to identify which entity in the batch failed and that can be done by capturing StorageException and inspecting RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation property. Take a look at the screenshot below especially for ErrorCode and ErrorMessage. What I have done here is made 2nd entity in my batch fail in a delete entity batch operation. You'll get ErrorCode as "ResourceNotFound" but what's interesting is ErrorMessage. If you see, you get ErrorMessage as "1:The specified resource does not exist". It basically gives you the index of the entity which failed in the batch.

[image]

What you could do then is split the batch in 3 parts - ones before this failed entity, this failed entity (single item) and then entities after this failed entity and try them in separate operations.

Comment: Thank you. Would not have known that was the failed index if you hadn't shown it. I ended up just removing the failed index from the TableBatchOperation and try again recursively. Works best in my case.

Comment: Follow-up: Sometimes the ErrorMessage does not start with an index. What does that mean?

Comment: Can you describe the error message? Does it still say "The specified resource does not exist"? Could it be related to table not present in the storage account.

Comment: I only do queries on one table, so it's not that. The message is:
"The specified resource does not exist.
RequestId: 168e8512-42c2-413f-b3ad-173497173058
Time:2013-01-14T12:17:05:4870374Z"

Comment: And you get the same error message with the code above i.e. with entity batch transaction where you're trying to delete entities in a batch?

Comment: Yes. You set me on a path here, and I think I found why this happens. It seems to be when there is only one operation in the TableBatchOperation, and that one fails. The recursive removal I mentioned ended up removing failed operations until there was only one operation left :)

Comment: That's weird! I tried adding a single entity in a delete batch operation which doesn't exist in the table and I got "0:The specified resource does not exist".

Comment: Huh... weird indeed.. my problem seems to be gone though. I am using the latest SDK if that makes a difference.

Comment: I too am using latest SDK. Good thing is that the problem is solved :)

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking is the Failed Operation Index of a Batch operation.

I have implemented an extension class for StorageExtension that provides methods to extract useful information including the failed operation index.

Have a look at: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AzureStorageExceptionParser/

It provides extension methods to extract
        - ErrorCode
        - ETag
        - ExtendedErrorMessage
        - FailedOperationIndex (of a failed Batch Operation)
        - HttpStatusCode
        - OperationStartTime (UTC)
        - OperationEndTime (UTC)
        - RequestDate (UTC)
        - RequestId
        - TargetLocation (Primary, Secondary, etc.)
        - IsOptimisticConcurrencyFailure