# What happens if one operation of TableBatchOperation fails?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

When executing a batch, if one of the operation of TableBatchOperation fails:

1. Every operations in the batch are canceled
2. Every other operations that are valid are processed
3. The first valid operations in the queue are processed until one operation fails, and following ones are not processed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answer is 1 - Even if one operation fails in the batch, the entire operation fails (or in other words rolls back). This is similar to performing transactions in a relational database. What's interesting is that you get an index of the failed entity in the response when this happens. Check this thread for more details: [Azure CloudTable.ExecuteBatch(TableBatchOperation) throws a storageexception. How can I find which operation(s) caused the exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282385/azure-cloudtable-executebatchtablebatchoperation-throws-a-storageexception-ho/14290910#14290910)

Answer (score 5):

Official blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/11/06/windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-tables-deep-dive.aspx

> TableBatchOperations, or Entity Group Transactions, are executed
>   atomically meaning that **either all operations will succeed** or if there
>   is an error caused by one of the individual operations **the entire
>   batch** will fail.